# Absolute file path for java script

Tags: javascript, reference, absolute

I have a small javascript library written by myself. I want to reference it in my web application, but it doesn't work

```
<script src='file:\\C:\Path\To\Script\Script.js'></script>
```

Is it possible to reference javascript when all you know is the absolute path?

Comment: Is your web application locally or on the we or under a fake/real domain/ip?

Comment: Niklas, it's hosted on localhost

Comment: Any reason you can't copy it in your web application folder and reference it with relative path instead of absolute?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `file:` url needs **3** forward slashes, and the path also needs forward slashes:

```
<script src='file:///C:/Path/To/Script/Script.js'></script>
```

This will ofcourse only work if you load the script within a html-file on your disk that's loaded in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm a Mac guy, my (limited) understanding of Windows security is that it has restrictions around running Javascript files "locally." Your best bet would be to copy the file to your web application's directory structure and reference it through a relative path.

Not only will this provide greater reliability, but it's also one less thing to remember to include when deploying to a web server or somesuch. If the JS file is outside your app's folder structure, when deploying to a remote server you'll have to include it anyways.