# how to load svg file using absolute path

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am trying to load SVG files from my LocalDrive using absolute path, I have tried with the below code, it works fine when i use relative path, but its not working with the absolute path.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('button').click(function () {

                $('#pagediv').load('D:/newfolder1/newfolder2/WebApplication/pic1.svg');


            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: use file:/// prefix http://stackoverflow.com/a/6395575/2375207

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this is intended to be run like most JQuery in a web page which you are viewing from your local hard drive using. In which case you would need the URL to the file. Remember that a web browser simply should not allow you to access files locally but as the html you are viewing is also local your computer is acting like a server until you call for the absolute path and then it attempts to protect you as it should.

It has been a long while since I have toyed with that sort of thing but you might be able to force the computer to carry on serving up to you be specifying "file://" where http:// would normally go but even so that would mean that the browser allowed local file use which would be a security concern. On the other hand it is possible that giving the protocol part of the path as "http://" might work but I am just guessing now. To be honest this is not really the best way to do what you are doing but if you really want to then I suggest you play with the protocol prefix and see what you can get the browser to do for you.