# JavaScript animate function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what the code looks like.

```
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\User\Desktop\css1.css" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\js.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="header_wrap">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="logo">
        LOGO
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
        <a href="http://www.google.se">
          Stuff
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
          Other stuff
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
          More stuff
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="mobile_nav"></div>
      <div class="mobile_nav_menu">
        <div class="mobile_menu">
          <span>Stuff</span>
          <span>Other stuff</span>
          <span>More stuff</span>
        </div>
        <div class="mobile_close">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="image_container">
  <div class="inner_content" id="slide1">
    <h2>
      CONTENTS
    </h2>
  </div>
    <a class="button" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
</div>
</body>
```

the .js file contains this code

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $("#slide1").css('opacity', '1');
},800);

setInterval(function(){
  $(".button").toggleClass("opacity");
},1000);
//Navigation
$(".mobile_nav").click(function() {
  $(".mobile_nav_menu").animate({right: 0});
})
$(".mobile_close").click(function() {
  $(".mobile_nav_menu").animate({right: -270});
})
```

Can anyone help me out with what I'm doing wrong and how it can be fixed?

Thank you! /AJ

UPDATE: The .js loads (tried the alert function), but does not fill the function it should. Original pen can be found on http://codepen.io/yuriylianguzov/pen/qjwEe

Comment: are you seeing any console errors?

Comment: You are toggling a class called 'opacity'. Do you have a class called opacity?

Comment: Hi Anna, I think you need to get the very basics of JavaScript before trying to run with something a bit more complex. Your JavaScript is trying to attach to some elements that don't exist in your HTML - e.g. #slide1 or .button

Comment: does the JS load if you host it elsewhere?

Comment: @BigChris, i found both of those elements in the HTML

Comment: @rybo111, if there wasn't before toggling, there would be after.

Comment: `<script src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\js.js"></script>` Does this work? I didn't realize you could do that on Windows.

Comment: I think you would also benefit from installing a "local" webserver on your computer so you can program as close to "real world" sites so you don't learn bad habits. Windows? Look up XAMPP - easily installed in a matter of minutes and you can play with new code the way they're supposed to work. That's if you want to learn, say, PHP...

Comment: Have you tried the code without the dropbox link?  It might be loading the html file that I am seeing.  You could also try putting a `console.log("Loaded js");` at the beginning of the javascript file.  Are you sure that `C:\Users\User\...` is the right directory?

Comment: @smerny There are no errors, except for the fact that the functions that are supposed to make the navigation expand does not react.

Comment: @smerny - my bad! I just found them too. Sorry Anna!

Comment: Are you sure that it's not loading?  Try adding alert(); in your first function and see if something pops up on your screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute file path for java script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395367/absolute-file-path-for-java-script)

Comment: @uxonith I've tried the codes both separately and together and nothing seems to work.

Comment: @Chasesandmann Thank you! It loads but it just doesn't work then, which is strange since the js-code is straight off codepen.

Comment: Could it be that Windows is blocking it out due to safety restrictions?

Comment: Copy your code to jsfiddle. If it works there, it is a URL problem.

Answer (score 4):

One of the problems is that you are trying to reference a javascript file from a physical file path, and not a url (or relative path).  You can't use your harddrive path in an html file to include javascript.

```
<script src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\js.js"></script>
```

If your javascript is in the same folder as your html, try something like this:

```
<script src="js.js"></script>
```

I'm not exactly sure what the expected behavior for the JavaScript is, because it appears to be doing what it is intended to do.  If you look at the DOM in the codepen link that you provided the element with the id of 'slide1' has its opacity style set to 1 (see below) and the anchor tag with class of 'button' is getting the class 'opacity' toggled on and off every second (not depicted below, but you can see it happening in firebug).

```
<div class="image_container">
    <div id="slide1" class="inner_content" style="opacity: 1;">
    <h2>
      We are who we choose to be.
    </h2>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button"></a>
</div>
```

The other two click handler's are targeting empty elements (the element with class of 'mobile_nav', and the element with class of 'mobile_close') so they aren't going to do anything.

```
$(".mobile_nav").click(function() {
    $(".mobile_nav_menu").animate({right: 0});
})
$(".mobile_close").click(function() {
    $(".mobile_nav_menu").animate({right: -270});
})

<div class="mobile_nav"></div>

<div class="mobile_nav_menu">
     <div class="mobile_menu">
    <span>Projects</span>
    <span>Profile</span>
    <span>Contact</span>
     </div>
     <div class="mobile_close"></div>                           
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Actually the javascript loads from the local file (I got tipped to try it with the alert function). The problem is that it does not perform the task it is supposed to perform. Check my update on the first post :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Some of the elements your javascript is acting on don't have any content

2) Change the line `$(".mobile_nav_menu").animate({right: 0});` to: `$(".mobile_nav_menu").animate({"right": "0"});` and do the same with the other one, though it won't have any functionality, really.

3) your class mobile_nav_menu needs to have css that says `position:relative` for the attribute "right" to work.

4) I'd recommend moving your mobile_close div outside the mobile_nav_menu div so it doesn't move when you click it

If anyone has stuff to add, please do so.

Comment: If you look at the codepen (http://codepen.io/yuriylianguzov/pen/qjwEe) and make the window less wide, and click the menu logo you will see what the function i'm trying to apply is. Unfortunately it does not work at all, even though it works on the codepen..